# How do I keep Pandoc from making "# of People" a header

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I have a Pandoc / markdown Grid table where I want one cell to have the contents "# of People".  I tried this:

```
+-------------------+
| **Cell Content:** |
+===================+
| # of People       |
+-------------------+
```

Unfortunately, it converted that to this html:

```
<td align="left"><h1 id="of-People">of People</h1></td>
```

If I put '' around the # (i.e. '#' of People), it doesn't treat it as a header, but it does keep the ''.

Is there any way to get Pandoc to not process the # as a header level marking, without having to add extra visible characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a backslash to escape the #:

```
\# of People
```